# programmatically enable application verifier

Tags: application-verifier

I have a program(a unit test runner) called foo.exe that I would like to run with a certain set of application-verifier flags. This program is run as part of a continuous integration system, on various computers, to check for bugs. I'd like to programmatically enable application verifier, run my unit tests, then reset the system state so that application-verifier does not run on any similarly-named programs run by other developers(the fact that our CI system doesn't fully-sanitize between builds is a separate issue beyond this scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a whim, I decided to check if application-verifier had any command-line flags. For more flags, run `appverif -?`

## To enable application verifier heap+handle checks

```
appverif -enable heaps handles -for foo.exe
```

## To remove application verifier settings

```
appverif -delete settings -for foo.exe
```