# Adjust Image File Execution Options per process invocation

Tags: windows, winapi, application-verifier

How can I adjust the Image File Execution Options per-process invocation(like a CreateProcess call)?

It is possible to [programmatically enable application verifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62663909/programmatically-enable-application-verifier), but this works by creating a persistent registry key in hkey_local_machine that affects all processes, and requires administrator access to do so. I'd like to enable the equivalent of specific application verifier checkboxes for individual processes, not per-exe.

Comment: This is simply not possible due to how the functionality is implemented.

Comment: Why do you need this? Attaching a debugger or something else?

Comment: @Luke, bummer, if you can find a reference for that and post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Anders, we'd like to run our unit tests with certain combinations of increased IFEOs, but for security policy reasons we don't want to open that part of HKLM for write access to the user executing these tests, we don't want to require each unit test to have a unique name, and we don't want to risk adjustments from one unit test executable impacting another.